# Pod is in pending stat

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have made a custom scheduler like below:

```
root@kmaster:~# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/my-scheduler.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=false
    - --port=10261
    - --secure-port=10269
    env:
    - name: no_proxy
      value: ',10.74.46.2,10.74.46.3,10.74.46.4'
    - name: NO_PROXY
      value: ',10.74.46.2,10.74.46.3,10.74.46.4'
    - name: HTTPS_PROXY
      value: http://127.0.0.1:3129
    - name: HTTP_PROXY
      value: http://127.0.0.1:3129
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.22.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: my-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
root@kmaster:~#
```

My customer scheduler pod is running successfully:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
coredns-78fcd69978-6dcft          1/1     Running   10 (2d19h ago)   47d
coredns-78fcd69978-8224d          1/1     Running   10 (2d19h ago)   47d
etcd-kmaster                      1/1     Running   4 (21h ago)      15d
kube-apiserver-kmaster            1/1     Running   68 (2d19h ago)   47d
kube-controller-manager-kmaster   1/1     Running   33 (21h ago)     47d
kube-flannel-ds-nvpgz             1/1     Running   11 (2d19h ago)   47d
kube-flannel-ds-xnvvw             1/1     Running   11 (2d19h ago)   47d
kube-flannel-ds-ztgql             1/1     Running   4 (2d19h ago)    47d
kube-proxy-h2t7s                  1/1     Running   4 (2d19h ago)    47d
kube-proxy-pq9t4                  1/1     Running   10 (2d19h ago)   47d
kube-proxy-vgcw7                  1/1     Running   8 (2d19h ago)    47d
kube-scheduler-kmaster            1/1     Running   0                21h
my-scheduler-kmaster              1/1     Running   0                7h17m
```

Then created a pod using that scheduler:

```
root@kmaster:~# cat my_pod.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: webapp-color
  name: webapp-color
spec:
  containers:
  - image: 10.74.46.13:5000/webapp-color:v1
    name: webapp-color
  schedulerName: my-scheduler
root@kmaster:~#
```

But my pod is in pending state:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl get pod
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
webapp-color   0/1     Pending   0          4h12m
root@kmaster:~#
```

Describe the pod:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl describe pod webapp-color
Name:         webapp-color
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         <none>
Labels:       run=webapp-color
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  webapp-color:
    Image:        10.74.46.13:5000/webapp-color:v1
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mkh4z (ro)
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-mkh4z:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
root@kmaster:~#
```

Kubernetes version:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.22.0
Server Version: v1.22.0
root@kmaster:~#
```

Please help me to find why pod is in pending state.
Not getting any clue.

Pending means custom scheduler is not working. But not getting any reason.

Regards

Comment: Any logs from your scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

The job of the scheduler is to decide what node a pod is going to run on. Until the scheduler decides this, the pod will be in pending state. It seems that your scheduler is not working properly.

Try looking into the logs with: `kubectl logs kube-scheduler-kmaster -n kube-system`

To see if the scheduler is making any decisions.